# Angularjs routeprovider multiple routes lead to same view

Tags: angularjs, routes, internationalization, ngroute

So, the workflow with angularjs $routeProvider goes as following,

```
    $routeProvider
    .when('/main1', {
        templateUrl: 'view1.html',
    })
    .when('/main2', {
        templateUrl: 'view2.html',
    })
```

My question is, is there any way of simplifying the following code. If when('/main1') and when('/main2') point to the same template. So,

```
    $routeProvider
    .when('/main1', {
        templateUrl: 'view1.html',
    })
    .when('/main2', {
        templateUrl: 'view1.html',
    })
```

The question is asked because if we have multiple languages on the site, and we want to have multiple translations of the url.

Another solution would be to recognize if the site is using .com or .de for instance, and thus adjust to the correct /main1 or /main2 translation. So for instance,

```
var url = window.location.href;
var main;
if (url.match(/.de/) !== null){
    main = "/main1";
}else{
   main = "/main2";
}

$routeProvider
.when(main, {
    templateUrl: 'view1.html',
})
```

But semantically, this doesn't seem to be the best solution as I like to keep configuration options set in the run block after the config. We also can't inject factories (only providers, I may be mistaken though) to config.

Comment: Why not make it something like '/main/:lang'? Then you can have 'main/DE/' or 'main/EN/', you can detect which language it is from $routeParams and they are covered with one routing rule, when('/main/:lang', {template: 'view.html'}

Comment: But I'm more concerned about breadcrumbs being translated. So for instance, for .com, we'd have .com/animals/dog. But for German, we'd have .de/Tier/Hund. But perhaps I can do something like .com/:animal/:type, and then assign for german it to be Tier and Hund?

Comment: Ok, so you want to have translated URL? First question is: how do you plan to have .com and .de, are you speaking about something like www.webpage.com and www.webpage.de? Because that is not the same domain anymore

Comment: It will be a sub app of a domain, so let's say we have. mainapp.com/subapp, if it is mainapp.de/subapp/animals will be used, if it is mainapp.com/subapp/tier will be used.

Comment: Hm that means one app par domain, correct? Which means you will serve multiple applications?

Comment: Well, basically it's like this. I have made an app(sub app) that sits ontop of another app (main-app). The main app can be .de/.com etc. The sub-app recognizes if main-app is .de or .com, and changes languages for both text and breadcrumbs. Do you understand it? My solution at the moment is calling a function inside config, to determine which main-app it sits on and choose breadcrumbs/language after that. It works, but semantically, I don't like how it looks.

Comment: Ok, I understand! So what you want to do is generate routes depending on detected language in some nice way, correct?
If so, I would recommend following: create a service (or constant) for localization, where you will have translations for each term (for example, under 'dog' you will have {'en': 'dog', 'de': 'hund', ...}). Then, when defining routes, define them using that service: .when(loc('animal') + '/' + loc('dog'), {template: dog.html}) and so on. I did not explain all details here, but you will get them, if not ask. Is this all, or did I miss something?

Comment: Or small alternation of what I defined above: define translations for each url, like '/animal/dog': {en: 'animal/dog', de: 'tier/hund'} so now you do not have to do composition (which may look somewhat ugly) inside when().

Comment: I did something like that, except I just made it as a function, then called that before $routeProvider.when({Url['Animal'], ...}). I would make it a service, but you cannot inject services in the config of an app, only providers. I just thought it would be a more clean way of doing it, as I'm doing a lot of initialization in the run() segment after config, but ideally, I would just like to make them all in either config (can't, since only providers), or the run() block.

Comment: Ok great, I know you can not use service in config but you can use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant, so try that, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for putting the language as first url segment in the route.

```
$routeProvider.when('/:lng/main', {
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    controller: function($routeParams){
        var lng = $routeParams.lng;
    }    
})
```

Though it would be really nice if the `$routeProvider` would provide this functionality where the an url segment can be isolated. I ain't that pretty putting `:lng` in each route.